# When truncating an AES MAC value by "w" , how do I justify that "w" is still negligible?

Tags: aes, mac, negligible

I'm taking an online class on cryptography at corsera.org / Stanford, and the professor is explaining that it's OK to truncate an AES MAC to $w$ bits as long as $1/2^w$ is still negligible (say $w > 63$)

- Where did the value $1/2$ come from?
- How is 64 and above negligible?
- What is non-negligible today (5/17/2013) and in the future (5/17/2020)?

Comment: That's a misuse of the term negligible. Negligibility is defined for functions. (Roughly the function is dominated by the inverse of any polynomial for large enough input values.) No constant non-zero function (such as $2^{-63}$) can ever be negligible.

Comment: @Maeher, I have a different take.  I think it's a perfectly reasonable use of the term.  Outside of complexity theory, the standard engineering meaning of the term "negligible" is "so small it can be safely ignored/safely treated as zero".  That seems to apply fine here.

Comment: That may be the case, but in the area of cryptography it is very uncommon to use the term outside of the context of asymptotic security.

Comment: I learned something new today http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the factors that determines how hard it is to forge a MAC for a given message is how long the MAC is. If it's 1 bit long, you can definitely produce the correct MAC in two tries.

$2^n$ is the number of possible bit-strings of length $n$; $1/2^n$ is the probability that any random bit-string happens to be the MAC (of length $n$) for a given message and key.

Negligible depends on what you're protecting with your MAC, who your attacker is, and what information / oracles they have access to. In particular, if the attacker has to make some kind of service request to a single point to check that a MAC is valid, $2^{64}$ is an awful lot of requests – this is probably the assumption being made when it was stated that MACs of length 64 or more are secure.

Not all MACS can be truncated safely however. AES-GCM [loses more security than expected by truncation](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/comments/CWC-GCM/Ferguson2.pdf), but HMAC is fine.

Given a MAC construction *that can be safely truncated*, truncating it to 128 bits is unlikely to pose a problem for a long time ($\gg$2020), for any attacker capability.

Comment: Is it correct for me to think/say "negligible in terms of brute forcing".  Does negligible apply to any other attack other than brute forcing?

Comment: You were doing so well until the last sentence. Poly1305 and AES-GCM cannot be truncated, due to algebraic properties they have despite being information theoretically secure.

Comment: forgot to ping @Watson for requested edit

Comment: @WatsonLadd Do you have some reference for this observation on AES-GCM?

Comment: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/comments/CWC-GCM/Ferguson2.pdf Because of the nature of the polynomial authenticator, there is a security gap that increases for small authenticator sizes. $p(x)$ has $d$ roots, so the chance of picking one is $d/q$ where $q$ is the field size. Here $q=2^k$, and so for small $k$ this is a bigger gap proportionally.